# Java Clock issues

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am trying to implement the following in my code:

1. Every time I set the alarm and click 'set alarm' the leading zeros I pick from the drop down don't get registered into the jLabels next to alarm.  Only the numbers show up.  How can I fix this?

Updated code:

```
package hw4;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TypeAlarmClock extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form TypeAlarmClock
 */
public TypeAlarmClock() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Type Alarm Clock");

    jLabel1.setText("Clock:");

    jLabel2.setText("Alarm ON");

    jLabel3.setText("Alarm OFF");

    jLabel4.setText("Set Alarm:");

    jLabel5.setText("Hours");

    jLabel6.setText("Minutes");

    jButton1.setText("Set Alarm");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel7.setText("Alarm:");

    jToggleButton1.setText("Alarm On/Off");
    jToggleButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel8.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel8.setText("10    :");

    jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel9.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel9.setText("09    :");

    jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel10.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel10.setText("00");

    jLabel11.setText(":");

    jButton2.setText("Reset");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jMenu1.setText("Options");

    jMenuItem1.setText("Change background color");
    jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);
    jMenu1.add(jSeparator1);

    jMenuItem2.setText("Change font");
    jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                    .addComponent(jLabel12)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jLabel11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jLabel13)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)))
                    .addGap(92, 92, 92))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 52, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(68, 68, 68)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 71, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(63, 288, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addGap(23, 23, 23))))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(51, 51, 51)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(40, 40, 40)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addComponent(jLabel11)
                .addComponent(jLabel12)
                .addComponent(jLabel13))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addComponent(jLabel6))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // Used to change background color
    Color backgroundColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(this, "Choose background color", Color.white);
    getContentPane().setBackground(backgroundColor);
}                                          

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // Take entered values for hours and minute and pass them into Alarm label
    String hr = jTextField1.getText();
    int h = Integer.parseInt(hr);
    String outHr = Integer.toString(h);
    //System.out.println(a);
    jLabel12.setText(String.format("%0d", outHr));
    jTextField1.setText("");

    String min = jTextField2.getText();
    int m = Integer.parseInt(min);
    String outMin = Integer.toString(m);
    //System.out.println(a);
    jLabel13.setText(outMin);
    jTextField2.setText("");
}                                        

private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // Change color of Alamr ON/OFF label when toggle butotn pressed

    if(jToggleButton1.isSelected()){

        jLabel3.setForeground(Color.black);
        jLabel2.setVisible(true);
        jLabel2.setForeground(Color.red);

    }
    else{

        jLabel2.setForeground(Color.black);
        jLabel3.setVisible(true);
        jLabel3.setForeground(Color.red);

    }

}                                              

private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // Change font of JLabels
    Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14);
    jLabel1.setFont(font);
    jLabel2.setFont(font);
    jLabel3.setFont(font);
    jLabel4.setFont(font);
    jLabel5.setFont(font);
    jLabel6.setFont(font);
    jLabel7.setFont(font);

}                                          

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // Blank out Alarm when Reset is pressed
    jLabel12.setText("");
    jLabel13.setText("");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The alarm has been reset");
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TypeAlarmClock.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TypeAlarmClock.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TypeAlarmClock.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TypeAlarmClock.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new TypeAlarmClock().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: You are focusing on quite many things at once here. I would recommend making your question only trying to solve one of your issues at a time. As it currently stands, your question might get closed as "too broad".

Comment: ok I will edit out the other questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every time I set the alarm and click 'set alarm' the leading zeros I pick from the drop down don't get registered into the jLabels next to alarm. Only the numbers show up. How can I fix this?

Don't confuse numbers with Strings. The former represents the abstract concept of number, and for this leading 0's are meaningless, while the latter is the display of the number for the user to see.

I think that the best and easiest way solve this is to not even worry about leading 0's that the user enters, but rather decide in advance how many digits you wish your clock to display, including leading 0's if needed, and display all those digits. This can easily be done with either `String.format("%05d", number)` or using `DecimalFormat.format(...)`.

As a side recommendation, your code is crying out to use arrays or ArrayLists to simplify and make more efficient.

---

> so that was what I have tried but my program keeps crashing. Where in my code under jButton1ActionPerformed, I implement that and how? This is how I typed it: jLabel12.setText(String.format("%02d", outHr)); (jLabel is my label for hours)

Re-read your code that's causing the error, because that's **not** how you've typed it.

Comment: Thanks, so that was what I have tried but my program keeps crashing.  Where in my code under jButton1ActionPerformed, I implement that and how? This is how I typed it: jLabel12.setText(String.format("%02d", outHr)); (jLabel is my label for hours)

Comment: @RashmiPatel: for best help you should create and post a valid [mcve]. Otherwise it will be hard for us to run and test your code.

Comment: I updated the code so that it can run.

Comment: @RashmiPatel: and obviously did so without first reading the link that I've provided -- not good. In doing so, you've posted a huge program with much code completely unrelated to the problem at hand, forcing volunteers to slog through tons of code trying to find that which has meaning to the problem. Please be kind to the volunteers who try to help you in their free time -- create a true [mcve]. Again please read the link before posting, as it needs to be runnable, but a ***LOT*** shorter.

Comment: @RashmiPatel: see edit to answer

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I am running into a issue for a piece of code that when the button is clicked on, it increments but I want the increment to only go to 24 and then loop back to 0, how do I modify my code to do this?

Comment: @RashmiPatel: If you have a new problem, you ask a new question on this site. Please don't completely change your current question.